# SQL INSERT INTO returning autoincrement field

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I'm a long time desktop app C++ programmer new to SQL.  I need to insert into a table with an autoincrment field, and have that sql statement return the new value for the autoincrement field.

Something LIKE:

```
INSERT INTO Entrys ('Name','Description')
VALUES ('abc','xyz')
SELECT Entrys.EntryID WHERE EntryID=[THE ONE JUST INSERTED!]
```

Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: what database are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Answer (score 4):

select scope_identity

```
insert into table values ('string value');select scope_identity()
```

Details [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303448-return-identity-after-sql-insert.html)

Comment: Is that from: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303448-return-identity-after-sql-insert.html ? If so you should provide a link.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're using SQL Server, you can use [scope_identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to return "the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch."

```
INSERT INTO Entrys ('Name','Description') VALUES ('abc','xyz');
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, you can also use the OUTPUT clause on your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Entrys('Name', 'Description') 
OUTPUT Inserted.EntryID
VALUES ('abc','xyz')
```

This will output the newly created IDENTITY field value.

Comment: If multiple VALUES tuples are specified, are returned IDs guarantee to be in the same order as the values tuples?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 0):

As @marc_s said for SQL Server, in PostgreSQL you can obtain the same behaviour with:

```sql
INSERT INTO Entrys ('Name','Description')
VALUES ('abc','xyz')
RETURNING EntryID;
```

RETURNING is also really useful when you're inserting several tuples and you want all the generated IDs for each of the rows.